# how to call an angular scope with dynamic variable name?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

Lets say i have 2 scopes defined in my controller as shown below

```
$scope.first = {a,b,c}
$scope.second = {d,e,f}
```

i want to use them in my html select list but the problem is that i can not call them directly since they are printed in an iteration.

The code doesn't work in the example below even though "attrName" becomes "first", and "second" once in the iteration. How to call those scopes?
Thanks in advance.

```
.control-group ng-repeat="(attrName, attrType) in attributes"
  .controls ng-switch="" on="attrType"
    div ng-switch-when="select"
      select ng-model="gvalue[attrName]" ng-options="c for c in attrName"
```

Answer (score 0):

you could just reference the name `first.a` or `second.e` for example.

but i don't really understand what you are asking... the whole point of the `$scope` object is to keep all the data related to a controller or directive in one place.

and you with the code above you don't really have two different `scopes` but rather two `objects` (`first` and `second`) within your one `$scope` object.